# Wordpress permalinks are showing as updated, but still point to an old permalink

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I have an issue with the taxonomy setup. If I create a category or a brand, say, for example, "Antica Barbieria Colla" and set the slug to /antica-barbieria-colla-2/ - when I go to site.com/product-category/antica-barbieria-colla-2 -> it works fine.

However, if I then go into the wp-admin, and edit the slug of this brand, to, for example, /antica-barbieria-colla/, ALL the links to this particular category still show as /antica-barbieria-colla-2/ - both in the admin panel (if I click "view" on the category), in wp-menu, and on the front-end.

/antica-barbieria-colla-2/ becomes a 404 (which it should). /antica-barbieria-colla/ becomes the correct taxonomy brand archive (which it should). All of the links in admin, wp-menu and on the front-end goto /antica-barbieria-colla-2/, but it's correctly set as /antica-barbieria-colla/

[Screenshot of this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06UUI.png)

I already tried to clear cache and reset Permalinks. WMPL is up to dated. If I turn WPML plugin off, the issue seems to be resolved, but this plugin is necessary for the website.

Comment: I know you reset the permalinks, but just in case, go to settings > permalinks and save twice as I've found in the past this seems to force them to update or change to a different type then back again.

Comment: Otherwise, it does sound like a cache issue, especially as disabling WPML seems to resolve it.

Comment: You can also try deleting your .htaccess file and then going to settings > permalinks and saving the options.